# How do I merge these two JavaScript functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to edit this example so that whenever the button is pressed, facebox still opens:
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qwLpf1vr/7/)

My goal is to make this popup window effect (called "reveal.facebox") in this [Demo](http://lilyclark.com/) work within the structure of the jsfiddle above.

Here's the full javascript for "reveal.facebox"

```
(function($) {
  $.facebox = function(data, klass) {
    $.facebox.init()
    $.facebox.loading()
    $.isFunction(data) ? data.call($) : $.facebox.reveal(data, klass)
  }

  $.facebox.settings = {
    loading_image : 'facefiles/loading.gif',
    close_image   : 'facefiles/closelabel.gif',
    image_types   : [ 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif' ],
    facebox_html  : '\
  <div id="facebox" style="display:none;"> \
    <div class="popup"> \
      <table> \
        <tbody> \
          <tr> \
            <td class="tl"/><td class="b"/><td class="tr"/> \
          </tr> \
          <tr> \
            <td class="b"/> \
            <td class="body"> \
              <div class="content"> \
              </div> \
              <div class="footer"> \
                <a href="#" class="close"> \
                  <img src="'+this.close_image+'" title="close" class="close_image" /> \
                </a> \
              </div> \
            </td> \
            <td class="b"/> \
          </tr> \
          <tr> \
            <td class="bl"/><td class="b"/><td class="br"/> \
          </tr> \
        </tbody> \
      </table> \
    </div> \
  </div>'
  }

  $.facebox.loading = function() {
    if ($('#facebox .loading').length == 1) return true

    $('#facebox .content').empty()
    $('#facebox .body').children().hide().end().
      append('<div class="loading"><img src="'+$.facebox.settings.loading_image+'"/></div>')

    var pageScroll = $.facebox.getPageScroll()
    $('#facebox').css({
      top:  pageScroll[1] + ($.facebox.getPageHeight() / 10),
      left: pageScroll[0]
    }).show()

    $(document).bind('keydown.facebox', function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 27) $.facebox.close()
    })
  }

  $.facebox.reveal = function(data, klass) {
    if (klass) $('#facebox .content').addClass(klass)
    $('#facebox .content').append(data)
    $('#facebox .loading').remove()
    $('#facebox .body').children().fadeIn('normal')
  }

  $.facebox.close = function() {
    $(document).trigger('close.facebox')
    return false
  }

  $(document).bind('close.facebox', function() {
    $(document).unbind('keydown.facebox')
    $('#facebox').fadeOut(function() {
      $('#facebox .content').removeClass().addClass('content')
    })
  })

  $.fn.facebox = function(settings) {
    $.facebox.init(settings)

    var image_types = $.facebox.settings.image_types.join('|')
    image_types = new RegExp('\.' + image_types + '$', 'i')

    function click_handler() {
      $.facebox.loading(true)

      // support for rel="facebox[.inline_popup]" syntax, to add a class
      var klass = this.rel.match(/facebox\[\.(\w+)\]/)
      if (klass) klass = klass[1]

      // div
      if (this.href.match(/#/)) {
        var url    = window.location.href.split('#')[0]
        var target = this.href.replace(url,'')
        $.facebox.reveal($(target).clone().show(), klass)

      // image
      } else if (this.href.match(image_types)) {
        var image = new Image()
        image.onload = function() {
          $.facebox.reveal('<div class="image"><img src="' + image.src + '" /></div>', klass)
        }
        image.src = this.href

      // ajax
      } else {
        $.get(this.href, function(data) { $.facebox.reveal(data, klass) })
      }

      return false
    }

    this.click(click_handler)
    return this
  }

  $.facebox.init = function(settings) {
    if ($.facebox.settings.inited) {
      return true
    } else {
      $.facebox.settings.inited = true
    }

    if (settings) $.extend($.facebox.settings, settings)
    $('body').append($.facebox.settings.facebox_html)

    var preload = [ new Image(), new Image() ]
    preload[0].src = $.facebox.settings.close_image
    preload[1].src = $.facebox.settings.loading_image

    $('#facebox').find('.b:first, .bl, .br, .tl, .tr').each(function() {
      preload.push(new Image())
      preload.slice(-1).src = $(this).css('background-image').replace(/url\((.+)\)/, '$1')
    })

    $('#facebox .close').click($.facebox.close)
    $('#facebox .close_image').attr('src', $.facebox.settings.close_image)
  }

  // getPageScroll() by quirksmode.com
  $.facebox.getPageScroll = function() {
    var xScroll, yScroll;
    if (self.pageYOffset) {
      yScroll = self.pageYOffset;
      xScroll = self.pageXOffset;
    } else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) {     // Explorer 6 Strict
      yScroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
      xScroll = document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
    } else if (document.body) {// all other Explorers
      yScroll = document.body.scrollTop;
      xScroll = document.body.scrollLeft;   
    }
    return new Array(xScroll,yScroll) 
  }

  // adapter from getPageSize() by quirksmode.com
  $.facebox.getPageHeight = function() {
    var windowHeight
    if (self.innerHeight) { // all except Explorer
      windowHeight = self.innerHeight;
    } else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight) { // Explorer 6 Strict Mode
      windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    } else if (document.body) { // other Explorers
      windowHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
    }   
    return windowHeight
  }
})(jQuery);
$(":not(#facebox)").click(function(){$("#facebox").hide();});

$(document).bind('beforeReveal.facebox', function() {
    var height = $(window).height() - 100;
    $('#facebox .content').css('height', height + 'px');
    $('#facebox').css('top', ($(window).scrollTop() + 10) + 'px');


});
```

And here is the code for the fiddle:

```
<div class="bouncyHouse">
  <button type="button">Click Me!</button>

  <div class="bouncer" data-vx='2' data-vy='-3'>
    <span>space</span>
  </div>
  <div class="bouncer" data-vx='-2' data-vy='2'>
    <span>space</span>
  </div>
  <div class="bouncer" data-vx='5' data-vy='2'>
    <span>space</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.bouncyHouse {
  height: 200px;
  width: 150%;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
}

.bouncer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  color: white;
}

.bouncer:nth-child(2) {
  top: 30px;
  left: 100px;
}

.bouncer:nth-child(3) {
  top: 50px;
  left: 200px;
}
```

Javascript

```
function hitLR(el, bounding) {
  if (el.offsetLeft <= 0 && $(el).data('vx') < 0) {
    //console.log('LEFT');
    $(el).data('vx', -1 * $(el).data('vx'))
  }
  if ((el.offsetLeft + el.offsetWidth) >= bounding.offsetWidth) {
    //console.log('RIGHT');
    $(el).data('vx', -1 * $(el).data('vx'));
  }
  if (el.offsetTop <= 0 && $(el).data('vy') < 0) {
    //console.log('TOP');
    $(el).data('vy', -1 * $(el).data('vy'));
  }
  if ((el.offsetTop + el.offsetHeight) >= bounding.offsetHeight) {
    //console.log('BOTTOM');
    $(el).data('vy', -1 * $(el).data('vy'));
  }
}

function mover(el, bounding) {
  hitLR(el, bounding);
  el.style.left = el.offsetLeft + $(el).data('vx') + 'px';
  el.style.top = el.offsetTop + $(el).data('vy') + 'px';

}

function moveIt() {
  $('.bouncer').each(function() {

    mover(this, $('.bouncyHouse')[0]);
  });
};
$htmlBack = $('.bouncer').clone();
moveInterval = setInterval(moveIt, 50);
$('button').on('click', function(){
    console.log(moveInterval);
    if( moveInterval != 0){
        clearInterval(moveInterval);
    $('.bouncer').remove();
    $('.bouncyHouse').eq(0).append($htmlBack);
        $htmlBack = $('.bouncer').clone();
    moveInterval = 0;
  } else {
        moveInterval = setInterval(moveIt, 50);
  }
});
```

Comment: add your html (or a minimal example of it) to your answer please

Comment: @LeonAdler - OP has posted the fiddle link. Please have a look at it.

Comment: @vijayP *"If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but also include the code in your question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time."* http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: re: "Not everyone can access external sites": how can they read this site but no others?

Comment: can you post a fiddle with the full code? inclduing the facebook. How are you trying to reveal it? with click on 'bouncer' div?